# Extract Specific key Word from long string

Tags: tableau-api

In my db i have long string with which length is not fixed

e.g.

> 4504065148...Leaving VENDOR on 01-01-1990;Please allow **7** - 10 days
>
> Case escalated, pending ETA
>
> Tentatively Leaving XYZ on 01-01-1990. Please allow **3** - 5 days.

so now I want to extract the number after allow key word i.e.7 or 3 using tablue

I had tried my work around but unable to find any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the number after allow is always a single digit.

```
if find([Column],'allow')>0 then mid([Column],find([Column],'allow')+6,1) end
```

[Column] is your column name. So if "allow" is present, then extract the next character after "allow ".